# Drupal 7 "flag" certain webform/entities fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, flags, entities, drupal-webform

When returning to the webform any time AFTER the original edit, I'm trying to "flag" certain fields to display the original information but "grayed-out" and non-editable. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to implement a more flexible solution, like for example to be able to set from the webform component settings which one should have the feature you describe, or is it just a one-time thing that you need for a single webform?

Comment: thank you for replying, we have a webform that gets filled out by a user. When the user returns to the form anytime in the future, we would like the original information to be still populated in the webform but grayed out or un-editable. I have started doing some research into the "Rules" and "Actions" module that I am guessing that those modules will be needed in conjunction with the Flags Module. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is just by not making it editable. Download and enable the module "Editable Fields". Then, when you are editing the filed that you want "grayed out", there will be an option called, "Field visibility and permissions". Under that click on "Custom Permissions", which will give you the option to uncheck the user's ability to edit the value for that field.

Once that is done, you won't see that field on the edit form anymore. If you want to see it on the edit form "grayed out", then also download and enable the module "Field Readonly". Once it is enabled, nothing more is required to do, it will appear on the form, but you won't be able to edit it.